# Aggregating Complex Array

Tags: r, concatenation, aggregation

Below is a shorter data frame of the one I currently have. It consists of duplicate id numbers, the month the item was purchased in, and what the item was:

```
id <- c('100','100','200','200','300','300','300','300')
month <- c(1,1,6,8,1,1,4,7)
purchase <- c('Apple','Apple','Banana','Orange','Apple','Apple','Pear','Melon')

df <- data.frame(id,month,purchase)
```

I am trying to use the aggregate function to concatenate this data frame so I can extract the first and second purchase the individual makes.

I would like to return something like this

```
id   combined purchase
100  [(1,'Apple'),(1,'Apple')]
200  [(6,'Banana'),(8,'Orange')]
300  [(1,'Apple'),(1,'Apple'),(4,'Pear'),(7,'Melon')]
```

that I can index accordingly.

There may be an easier way to do this but I am not sure. I would appreciate any feedback and assistance. Thank you!

Comment: `I can extract the first and second purchase the individual makes.` why `id` 300 has 4 entries ? and what data structure is that?

Comment: Some individuals have made more than 2 purchases. I am concerned (for now) about the first two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `toJSON` from `jsonlite`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(combinedpurchase = list(toJSON(unname(data.frame(month, 
                as.character(purchase))))))
```

Comment: I think it worked but how do I print the results out? The combined purchase column is hidden with <S3:json>.

Comment: @robert It is a list column, you can get it by extracting the column `%>% .$combinedpurchase`